# How to put initialized selectizejs input field in sweetalert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selectize.js

I have a page containing DataTables with actions buttons on each row. One of the buttons should open up a sweet alert containing my selectizejs input field. So the user can select or remove options from the list and then click "OK" in the sweet alert to save it.

I am stuck with the steps in between initializing the selectize element and placing it inside the sweet alert.

I do not see an option to initialize the selectizejs field inside the swal component, so I have tried numerous things initializing it before and placing it in the content field in sweetalert.

In my approach I have created my input element in my view :

```
<input type="text" id="adminvollabels" class="adminvollabels-select" value="test1,test2,test3" placeholder="<?=lang("flow_company_skills_placeholder")?>" name="adminvollabels">
```

The jQuery code is as this:

```
$('.vol-label-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userId = $(this).data("user-id");

    var ele = $('<div class="row"></div>');
    ele.append('<div class="col-md-12"><label for="adminvollabels">testlabel</label></div>');

    $('.adminvollabels-select').selectize({
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,
        create: function(input) {
            return {
                value: input.toLowerCase(),
                text: input.toLowerCase()
            }
        }
    });

    ele.append('<div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group">'+$('.adminvollabels-select')+'</div></div>');

    swal({
        title: res.VolLabelUpdateTitle,
        content: selectizeElement,
        icon: "info",
        buttons: {
            cancel: {
                text: res.BtnCancelText,
                visible: true,
                className: "btn-secondary"
            },
            confirm: "ok"
        }
    }).then(function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({
                //Do AJAX stuff
            });
        }
    })
});
```

In this approach my attempt was the following steps:

1) Create input element in HTML

2) when clicking on the vol-label-link element

3) (in JS) create a temporary DOM object with all the div's and col-md's

4) (in JS) Make the input field a selectize.js field

5) (in JS) Append this element in my temporary DOM object

6) place this temporary DOM object in the SWAL 'content' option.

Note on 6: Since I think that SWAL content option only allows raw HTML (I think it performs a parseHTML on it). Hence my attempt on building up the full HTML DOM temporary object before inserting it in the content field.

However with this code, my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12"><label for="adminvollabels">testlabel</label></div><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group">[object Object]</div></div>
```

I've been trying out with .clone() as well but I cannot get it working on the initialized selectizejs field.